# Likelihood ratio test for Bernoulli distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing

Let's say that we have sample $x_1, ..., x_n \sim \textrm{Bernouli}(\theta)$ and consider hypothesis: $H_0: \theta_0 = \theta$ and $H_1: \theta_0 \neq \theta$. I want to find form of likelihood ratio in in this case.

**Likelihood ratio connected with null hypothesis:**

$$f_0(x) = \theta^{\sum x_i}(1 - \theta)^{n - \sum x_i}$$

**Likelihood ratio connected with alternative hypothesis:**

Let's fix $\theta_1 \neq \theta$, then:

$$f_1(x) = \theta_1^{\sum x_i}(1 - \theta_1)^{n - \sum x_i}$$

**Likelihood ratio**

Our likelihood ratio is then given as:

$$\frac{f_0(x)}{f_1(x)} = \frac{\theta^{\sum x_i}(1 - \theta)^{n - \sum x_i}}{\theta_1^{\sum x_i}(1 - \theta_1)^{n - \sum x_i}}$$

Am I correct with my way of thinking or I'm missing something?

Comment: Your alternative hypothesis is not simple. In this case you have to evaluate the sup over all theta_1. That is to say, on the denominator you would have theta_1 replaced by its MLE. See for example the chapter on hypothesis testing by Casella & Berger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a hypothesis of the form $\theta \in \Omega_0$ and the "alternative" (this is an unfortunate misnomer) is $\theta \in \Omega_1;$ contrary to what the name would suggest, you need to have $\Omega_0 \subset \Omega_1.$ In your case, $\Omega_1 = (0,1)$ and $\Omega_0 = \{\theta_0\}.$ Then, you need to consider the ratio of the two likelihoods maximased over the null and alternative hypotheses:
$$
\Lambda = \dfrac{\sup\limits_{\theta \in \Omega_0} f(\theta)}{\sup\limits_{\theta \in \Omega_1} f(\theta)}.
$$
In your case, $\Lambda = \dfrac{f(\theta_0)}{f(\theta_\mathrm{MLE})}  = \dfrac{f(\theta_0)}{f(\bar X)}.$ Wilk's theorem asserts that $-2 \log \Lambda \approx \chi^2_{\mathrm{df}}$ if the sample size is large and where $\mathrm{df}$ is the difference of the dimension of $\Omega_1$ minus the dimension of $\Omega_0;$ in your case these dimensions are $1$ and $0,$ resp.

Thus, $-2 \log \Lambda \approx \chi^2_1.$

**Additional remarks:** note that $0 \leq \Lambda \leq 1$ so that $-2 \log \Lambda \in (0, \infty)$ and very large values of $-2 \log \Lambda$ are equivalent to very small values of $\Lambda.$ A very small value of $\Lambda$ *signifies* that the null hypothesis is much *less likely* than the "alternative" hypothesis; thus the alternative hypothesis ought to be preferred. (Note that the "null hypothesis" is, by definition, that hypothesis that you accept to be the "true" one in advance; only strong evidence against it should make you reconsider it for a different "alternative" hypothesis.) Wilk's theorem then asserts that one way to *measure the degree of discrepancy* between the null and alternative hypothesis is by the $\chi^2$-distribution. The amazin fact is that this distribution is *universal* (in the same sense that the normal distribution is universal in the $\mathsf{CLT}$).

Comment: Why the null hypothesis should be a subset of the alternative? I am not sure this is true...

Comment: That's how Wilk's theorem is to be applied.

Comment: Ok :) but than I would say it in the answer, since the question is not about wilk's theorem. It is not true "in general" that the null hypothesis has to be a subset of the alternative. E.g. Neyman Pearson has two different point hypothesis.

Comment: That's true. But Neyman-Pearson is quite useless in practice while Wilk's theorem is quite useful. In Neyman-Pearson you specify the parameter space to be $\{\theta_0, \theta_1\}$ while in Wilks  the parameter space can (and should be) and open subset of $\mathbf{R}^q.$ No working statistician should believe that a "true" parameter has to fall between either of two options. In contrast, you can have a belief that a parameter should be something specific (like .5 for coin tossing) and Wilk's theorem allows to measure how inconsistent this belief is with observed data, something NP lacks totally

Comment: I see your point, even if H0 and H1 may also not be parameters(like in a test of independence) and in that case the concept of subset loses meaning... anyway I understand your point, even if I wonder if including H0 in the alternative does not make the power of the final test smaller...

Comment: As a minor point, a point is closed in R (but I understand that one may consider it of 0 dimension)